# Objective-C IOS 7 push notification save data when app not running?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I created ios application with push notification setup done all, everyone can chat with other in my app, and i will solved some problem:

**1) Solved:** When application not active but still running in background (not exit all) i can handle push notification and save in to database (SQLite) code:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    //some code here
}
```

**2) Solved:** When user completed exit my app, new message incomming and  user click on notification ballon and user can read new message, to do this i will using this code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    /* this code working when application not running */
    NSDictionary *remoteNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if(remoteNotif)
    {
        [self handleRemoteNotification:application userInfo:remoteNotif];
        return YES;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

**3 Not Solved and my problem need help**

- When user completed exit my app, new message incomming but user don't touch on notification bar, user open app by touch on app icon in iphone screen and this action i can't get any data for showing in app.

Please help

Comment: When notifications are missed you will have to handle it through server by writing one api which will fetch all the notifications like facebook, whats app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your app is not running and the user clicks in a push notification to open it you can get the data about this notification in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

As per [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html):

> If your app is not frontmost or not running, you handle the notifications by checking the options dictionary passed to the [application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) of your app delegate for either the [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey) or [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey) key.

But if the app is not running when a notification is received and the app is never opened by clicking this notification you **will not** get its data.

That together with the fact the push notifications are best effort only *(see note below)* tells us we should always have another method to fetch the information (just like [Chetan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3378996/chetan) said). So **never rely only on push**.

> **Important:** Delivery of notifications is a “best effort”, not guaranteed. It is not intended to deliver data to your app, only to notify the user that there is new data available.

Comment: Exactly. APNs isn't a messaging system, it's a notification system. A common mistake is to try and use a notification to deliver the message data. The proper have is to deliver a notification that message data is available on your service.

Comment: I should accepted your answer long time ago, sorry xD

Answer (score 0):

To answer to your 3 bullet if it is still not solved. There is a way in iOS 7.0 and later where you can send notifications and access its content without user tapping it.
So, the notification payload which you send has a parameter called **content-available**. You can view the payload parmaters in the following link:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

So when you set the **content available** to **1** and deliver the notification, iOS calls the below function even if the app is not in the background or foreground(must have remote notification enabled)

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler
```

Then you can use the userInfo dictionary to fetch your notification data.

Comment: no its not possible , if application is in suspended mode then you can , but if it is forced quit then no way you can't launch app